# how to update subdocument in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

my schema look like this:

```
{
"blogTitle":"Book"
"blogContent":"demo"
"blogrelatedLink":{
    "relatedBloogId:"123",
    "relatedBlogTitle":"abc"`
    }
}
```

and my code is:

```
const updateBlogs = async (req, res) => {
    const { blogId } = req.params;
    const re = /<("[^"]?"|'[^']?'|[^'">])*>/;

    if (re.test(req.params.blogTitle)) {
        sendError(400, "Unsuccessful", "Blog Title cannot be HTML", req, res);
    } else {
        try {
            let update = {};
            if (req.body.blogTitle) update.blogTitle = req.body.blogTitle;
            if (req.body.blogContent) update.blogContent = req.body.blogContent;
            let blog = await Blog.updateOne(
                { blogId },
                {
                    $set: update,
                },
                { runValidators: true }
            );
            sendResponse(200, "Successfull", blog, req, res);
        } catch (err) {
            sendError(400, "Blog can't be updated by given id", err, req, res);
        }
    }
};
```

what will be the code to update subdocument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update key should be in this `<main key name>.<sub key name>: <value to be update>` format, just put this before your update query,

```
if (req.body.blogrelatedLink) {
  for (let key in req.body.blogrelatedLink) {
    update['blogrelatedLink.' + key] = req.body.blogrelatedLink[key];
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/x8GIr7_SUt8)

Comment: i tried but still its not updating in my mongoDB but thank you @turivishal

Comment: the other fields are updating? is blogId mongo id? then convert it to object type `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(blogId)`

Comment: blogId is something i am providing or you can se its a custom id even you can change in mongo when i open its showing like this
(downKey) ↓ blogRelatedLinks : Array                         
(downKey)      ↓ 0 : Object                         
          _id: objectid(1233454),
          relatedBlogId: 12323454,
          relatedBlogTitle: "demo"

Comment: i am not sure there is some missing in your code, i have just added playgroud working link in my answer, you can just console and debug your code.

Comment: ok i will check but thank you @turivishal